# How to one change the value of the next input?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, checkbox

how can i one to one change the value of the next input?

this code doing check all or unchec all, but i want to check or uncheck one to one,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery('#topluekle').click(function() {  
        if(jQuery(this).attr('checked')) { 
            jQuery('input:checkbox').attr('checked',true); 
            jQuery('input:text').attr('value','E'); 
        } else { 
            jQuery('input:checkbox').attr('checked',false); 
            jQuery('input:text').attr('value','H');    
        } 
    }); 
});
```

**Sample code:**

```
<form>

    <? for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++) { ?>
        <input type="checkbox" id="pgun[]" name="pgun[]">
        <input size="1" type="text" name="degerler[]" id="degerler[]" value="H">
        <br />
    <? } ?>

    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="E" name="topluekle" id="topluekle">
        Check / Uncheck All *
    </label>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val) like,

```
jQuery('input:text').val('H');
```

and use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop) in place of [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr) like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery('#topluekle').click(function() {  
        if(jQuery(this).prop('checked')) { 
            jQuery('input:checkbox').prop('checked',true); 
            jQuery('input:text').val('E'); 
        } else { 
            jQuery('input:checkbox').prop('checked',false); 
            jQuery('input:text').val('H');    
        } 
    }); 
});
```

If you want to change value for each **checkbox click** then you can try,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery('input[name="pgun[]"]').click(function() {  
        var newVal=$(this).next('input:text').val()=='E' ? 'H' : 'E';
        $(this).next('input:text').val(newVal);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: hi, thanks for answer. i solved

    jQuery('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
     valim = jQuery(this).next('input:text').val();
      if(valim=="E") { 
       jQuery(this).next('input:text').val("H"); 
      } else {
       jQuery(this).next('input:text').val("E"); 
      }
    });

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#topluekle').click(function () {
        $('input[name="pgun[]"]').prop('checked', this.checked);
        $('input[name="degerler[]"]').val(this.checked ? 'E' : 'H');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It will change corresponding text box's value of checkbox

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    var txtObj = $('input:text');
    jQuery('input:checkbox').each(function(i){
        jQuery(this).click(function(){
            if(jQuery(this).attr('checked')) {
                $(txtObj[i]).val("E");
            } else {
                $(txtObj[i]).val("H");
            }
        });
    });
});
```